# Python Exception Handling - exception raised with a string message, excepted as list of characters

Tags: python, string, exception

I am trying to raise and except a custom exception with a message, but the message string prints as tuple of characters.
My error class:

```
class myError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.args = arg
```

And try-raise-except part :

```
try:
    raise myError('some message.')
except myError, e:
    print e.args
```

This when raised properly, prints:`

```
('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'm', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', '.', ' ')
```

Of course, I wanted 'some message. '.  What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `args` is already a member of `Exception`, and it is defined as:

> args 
>   The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor

So you assign a tuple with an iterable (a string **is** an iterable of characters) and end with a tuple of characters.

How to fix:

1. just use `args` from Exception:

   ```
   class myError(Exception):
       pass

   try:
       raise myError('message')
   except myError as e:
       print(e.args[0])
   ```
2. use a new member name:

   ```
   class myError(Exception):
       def __init__(self, arg):
           self.msg = arg

   try:
       raise myError('message',)
   except myError as e:
       print(e.msg)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need to declare `__init__` in Your Exception:

```
>>> class myError(Exception):
...     pass

>>> raise myError('some message.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.myError: some message.
```

Comment: Ok. I removed __init__(), but kept the try-except clause same. It prints ('some message. '). Two questions- (1) Why can I still call e.args, if there is nothing in class as 'args'. (2) I checked the  type of e.args, which says tuple, not string. Problem not fixed by removing __init__()

Comment: You could simply print `str(e)` instead of `e.args`